# MVC 3 FormsAuthentication and disabled user accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have noticed that if a user is still logged in or has a persistent cookie, even if he gets "banned", or disabled in the database (Users Table flags), the user can still access everything until that cookie goes away or the user logs out of the site. Great security right.

So I am putting together a ActionFilterAttribute that checks for this, the disturbing thing for me is I have to hit the database for every controller that his ActionFilterAttribute is applied to. There has to be a better way of doing this but I have not found one yet.

Any ideas would be awesome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There has to be a better way of doing this but I have not found one yet.

No there isn't. Sorry. If the notion of *disabled/banned user* exists only in your database there is no other way but hitting your database. ASP.NET only verifies the validity of the authentication cookie which is sent on each request. It doesn't even know what a disabled user means so you cannot expect it do more than it already does.

Comment: Hey Darin, nice hearing from you again sir.. What about creating a dataset of disabled account and caching it? Everytime a user gets flagged I could invalidate the cache... Just a thought. Then the filter could check it rather than hit the DB.

Comment: @CrazyCoderz, sure, storing this information in memory would be one solution. Be careful though as if your application is very successful and you start having millions of users (which is all I can wish you) you might run into problems. Not to mention that storing such information in memory means that you can no longer run in a web farm as 2 nodes won't share the same memory. This means that a user can be perfectly valid on one web server and disabled on another. So if you go that route be extremely careful and make sure to synchronize caches.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

1) You can validate whether the user authentication is valid by hooking session start. This way if the user has a persistent cookie, you can validate the username and expire the cookie if needed.

2) You can use a time based mechanism to check the user auth status every few requests (every 5mins or whatever). You could store the `lastChecked` timestamp value in the user session or in the auth cookie itself using the `UserData` field. This allows you recheck if the user auth cookie needs to be expired more frequently, but keeps database calls to a minimum.

Comment: If they have a persistent cookie authentication will always be valid. I tried something similar and this is what I have noticed.

Comment: I'm not talking about checking the auth cookie, I'm talking about hitting the database or whatever and checking the flags. If banned or disabled, expire the auth cookie.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Yes that is what I am currently doing with my filter, I am not fond of having to use property injection to get my Repository into the filter but it works.

Comment: Yeah that's always a bit messy with Attributes. I'd be tempted to move it out and hook into the authorization process (httpmodule or global). Of course this might not make it any cleaner depending on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

MyThis is the solution I came up with:

In the User Account Membership service add a function to return whether the user's account is still active.

```
public class UserAccountMembershipService : IMembershipService
{        
    public bool UserIsActive(Guid userId)
    {
        if (userId == new Guid()) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");
        MembershipUser user = _provider.GetUser(userId, true);
        return user.IsApproved;
    }
}
```

Override the AuthorizeAttribute as follows:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        IMembershipService membershipService = new UserAccountMembershipService();

        //Check to see if the user's account is still active
        bool isActive = false;
        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Guid userId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser(httpContext.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
            isActive = membershipService.UserIsActive(userId);
        }

        if (!isActive)
        {
            //If the user's account is no longer active log him/her out
            IFormsAuthenticationService FormsService = new FormsAuthenticationService();
            FormsService.SignOut();
        }
        //Call the base AuthorizationCore method
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) && isActive;
    }
}
```